# minimum of list vs constant

Tags: python, list

I wish to get the minimum of a list compared against a constant. So for the a below I'm hoping to **get [0.5,1] as a result**.

```
In [1]: a=[0.5,2]

In [2]: min(a,1)
Out[2]: 1
```

Also I do not understand what has happened below.

```
In [3]: min(a,[1,1])
Out[3]: [0.5, 2]
```

Basically what is the most efficient way to compare a list against a constant?

Comment: I highlighted the expected result. Your command just gives me 0.5. I need to compare both elements.

Answer (score 1):

This type of bug is a very good reason to upgrade to Python 3 if you can (and you probably can). There is no defined rule for ordering a list and an int, so Python 2 applies a rule called "arbitary but consistent" - basically, the types alone are used to define the order, and the exact values of the two objects are not considered. Python 3 will *tell you* that it doesn't know how to do this, instead of just giving a strange result:

```
>>> min([0.5,2], 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < list()
```

In any case, it seems like what you want is an *element-wise* comparison against the constant `1`, so that you get a list of results. You can get this explicitly with a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [0.5, 2]
>>> [min(b,1) for b in a]
[0.5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.

> min(iterable[, key])
>   min(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])
>
> ```
> Return the smallest item in an iterable or the smallest of two or more arguments.
> ```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min

```
min(min(a), 1)
```